# Resolving TypeError: event is undefined

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am attempting to take a user's postal code to request the representatives of the locality. For troubleshooting purposes, I am attempting to log the console of both the postal code and the url including the postal code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      //Wait until user submits postal code (ie. K2H6G7)
      $("form").on("submit", function(event) {
          var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
          event.preventDefault();
          var searchWord = $("#search").val(); //Take postalcode and apply to url
          var url = "https://represent.opennorth.ca/postcodes/" + searchWord + "/?format=apibrowser";
          console.log(searchWord);
          console.log(url) request.open('GET', url, true);
          request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState === 4) {
              if (request.status === 200) {
                //Connect to API, create cards for each politician instance
                var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
                data.representatives_centroid.forEach(representatives_centroid => {
                  const card = document.createElement('div');
                  card.setAttribute('class', 'card');
                  const img = document.createElement('img');
                  img.src = representatives_centroid.photo_url;
                  const p1 = document.createElement('p');
                  p1.textContent = `$ {
              representatives_centroid.party_name
            }
            $ {
              representatives_centroid.elected_office
            }
            $ {
              representatives_centroid.first_name
            }
            $ {
              representatives_centroid.last_name
            }
            `
                  const p2 = document.createElement('p');
                  p2.textContent = `$ {
              representatives_centroid.district_name
            }
            ` //Add data to card
                  container.appendChild(card);
                  card.appendChild(img);
                  card.appendChild(p1);
                  card.appendChild(p2);
                });
              } else {
                console.log('error');
              }
            }
          }
          request.send();
        }
        ());
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form">
  <form type="text" class="form-inline" role="form">
    <label for="address" name="postalcode">Enter an address or postal code</label>
    <input id="search" placeholder="Enter an address or postal code" type="text">
    <button id="go">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Find
  </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

The error message I receive is "TypeError: event is undefined". Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Instead of the whole readystatechange/readystate/status dance I'd recommend just adding an onload handler, assuming you don't need to support IE6 that should be fine :] Better yet - consider `fetch` which is a nicer API or jQuery's ( which you are already using) $.ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your closing brackets

```
$(document).ready(function() {   

//Wait until user submits postal code (ie. K2H6G7)
$("form").on("submit", function(event) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    event.preventDefault();
    var searchWord = $("#search").val();   //Take postalcode and apply to url
    var url = "https://represent.opennorth.ca/postcodes/" + searchWord + "/?format=apibrowser";
    console.log(searchWord);
    console.log(url)

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState === 4) {
            if (request.status === 200) {

                //Connect to API, create cards for each politician instance
                var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
                data.representatives_centroid.forEach(representatives_centroid => {
                    const card = document.createElement('div');
                    card.setAttribute('class', 'card');
                    const img = document.createElement('img');
                    img.src = representatives_centroid.photo_url;
                    const p1 = document.createElement('p');
                    p1.textContent = `${representatives_centroid.party_name} ${representatives_centroid.elected_office} ${representatives_centroid.first_name} ${representatives_centroid.last_name}`
                    const p2 = document.createElement('p');
                    p2.textContent = `${representatives_centroid.district_name}`

                    //Add data to card
                    container.appendChild(card);
                    card.appendChild(img);
                    card.appendChild(p1);     
                    card.appendChild(p2);
                });
        } else {
                console.log('error');
        }
    }
}
request.send();

//THESE //
 // Change from }());  to });
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but what is that about type in the form?

the type="text" is for inputs, and I think you need an action="/route/" instate of type in order to have an event and could prevent it.

Regards.-